# I have a problem with a module of odoo 12 it dosn't add access rights

Tags: python-3.x, security, odoo, odoo-12, erp

Please help. I'm just starting with odoo 12
I have 4 models declared on the same file and I'm importing 2 other models there too, all good until there, but when I add access rights to the ir.model.access.csv file it doesn't do anything, I already uncommented that on my manifest but it didn't changed anything
this is what I'm writing on my csv file

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id, perm_read, perm_write, perm_create, perm_unlink    
access_municipio,municipio contacto,model_municipio,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
access_comarca,comarca contacto,model_comarca,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
access_distrito,distrito contacto,model_distrito,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
access_barrio,barrio contacto,model_barrio,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
```

Comment: Where is the first line of the .csv file?

Comment: @armando-peña did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @fnaquira sorry I didn't, I changed technologies after that and had never worked with odoo again

Answer (score 0):

The header is missing, Odoo will fail to [convert](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/tools/convert.py#L823) and import the CSV file. When the `id` field name is not specified in the header, Odoo will just log an error message and ignore the importation.

You should see the following error message in the log:

ERROR db_name odoo.tools.convert: Import specification does not contain 'id' and we are in init mode, Cannot continue.

Try to add the following header:
`csv id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink`

Comment: The header is already on the csv file but its not working anyways. I even created a new database to install everything again and the rules just don't add

Comment: In your question you said that: "this is what I'm writing on my csv file" and the header is missing. Please update your question and show exactly what you did to add the security rules.